# Retrieve data from firebase database and show in UITable in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following database in the Firebase,
[image]

I am trying to retrieve data and show them in the UITable view. First I want to retrieve agreements from database. For now there is only one record for agreements but there going to be many records in the future. I tried the below code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    //self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    [[_firebaseDatabaseRef child:@"krib-60229"] observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *_Nonnull snapshot){
        self.allSnapshot = [NSMutableArray array];
        NSLog(@"%@",self.allSnapshot);
        NSLog(@"%s","TestTestTest");
        for(snapshot in snapshot.children){
            [self.allSnapshot addObject:snapshot];
        }
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 3;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.allSnapshot count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    FIRDataSnapshot *snapShot = [self.allSnapshot objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *testText = snapShot.value[@"landlordDisplayName"];

    cell.textLabel.text = testText;

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

I don't get anything retrieved or any error either. I tried putting NSLogs, but they are also not printing.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following lines.

```
 FIRDatabaseReference *rootRef= [[FIRDatabase database] referenceFromURL:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/agreements",<database-url>]];
    [rootRef observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot)
    {
        if (snapshot.exists)
        {
            NSLog(@“%@”,snapshot.value);            
        }
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

@property FIRDatabaseReference *ref;

### "Declare this ref property above"

```
self.ref=[[FIRDatabase database] reference];
[[_ref child:@"your_child_name"] observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.exists) {
        NSMutableDictionary *agreement = snapshot.value;
        NSLOG(@"%@" , agreement)
    }

}
 withCancelBlock:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {
 NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
}];
```

This works for me!